# Extension method with generics

Tags: flutter, dart, generics

I have an extension method:

```dart
extension When<T extends Object> on T {
  T? when(bool Function(T self) predicate, {T Function(T self)? otherwise}) {
    if (predicate(this)) return this;
    return otherwise?.call(this);
  }
}
```

It allows me to do some handling with inner variables and inner function results after testing them without the need for them to be saved in a variable.

Sometimes, when I wanted to use this with Widgets, it bothered me that I always need to cast it to Widget. So, I went and did the following extension, since it's more specific, the compiler uses it instead of the first.

```dart
extension WhenWidget<T extends Widget> on T {
  Widget? when(bool Function(T self) predicate, {Widget Function(T self)? otherwise,}) {
    if (predicate(this)) return this;
    return otherwise?.call(this);
  }
}
```

I asked myself, can I do something like this then?

```dart
extension When<R extends Object, T extends R> on T {
  R? when(bool Function(T self) predicate, {R Function(T self)? otherwise}) {
    if (predicate(this)) return this;
    return otherwise?.call(this);
  }
}
```

But this way all of my type inference goes away. What I wanted to do was create this extension in a way that knows how to handle super types. So, if I try and do:

```dart
final variable = 1.when((self) self.isEven, otherwise: (self) => self + 0.5)!;
```

The `variable` would be `num` and not `Object`.

#### Edit

To be more precise, what I get is that the actual `runtimeType` is in fact `double`, but if you try and use `.toInt()` or any inner method or whatever, it will warn you that you are trying to call that from a dynamic and that's not type-safe.

Comment: I'm confused by what you're observing when you say "it will warn you that you are trying to call that from a dynamic and that's not type-safe." If you try your code, you should observe that `variable` is of type `Object` (`R` is constrained to `Object`, `when` returns an `R?`, and `!` forces the `R?` to `R`).

Comment: Anyway, I'm fairly certain that compile-time type constraints cannot do what you want and that you would need to rely on a runtime `as R` cast.

Answer (score 1):

As I've asked in an issue. There is no way for me to do what I want (at the moment). If you want more information, you can look [here](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/52077#issuecomment-1516006669), I'm going to follow [this issue](https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/1674) as suggested in the comment linked before, so that when this new feature releases I'm aware. Thank you for the responses!

Answer (score 0):

Please replace this with following signature and usage

```dart
void main() {
  final variable = 1.when<num, int>(
    (self) => self.isEven,
    otherwise: (self) => self + 0.5,
  );

  print(variable?.toInt());
}

extension When on dynamic {
  R? when<R, T extends R>(bool Function(T self) predicate,
      {R Function(T self)? otherwise}) {
    if (predicate(this)) return this;
    return otherwise?.call(this);
  }
}
```

Output: `1`